# WP SQLite Query Executor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sqlite, windows-phone

I am building a WP application with SQLite db. I installed the sqlite-net package and did a trial app. The app works fine for all the basic CRUD operations, but I need to modify and enhance the code for handling complex and dynamic queries.

So I tried the following:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    string query = "select * from Person";

    var res = db.Execute(query); 
}
```

but there is an exception with no proper message. 
The method Execute() is accessed from the sqlite.cs class that is generated on installation the sqlite-net package.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: I am not WP developer but I think you can use try catch block....

Comment: I have, The message reads "Row", that is it. The exception goes like this {SQLite.SQLiteException: Row
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute(String query, Object[] args)
   at SQLiteTrial.MainPage.btnRead_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)}

Comment: "Row" means that your SQL command attempted to return a row, which is not allowed with `Execute`.

Comment: Execute method return number of rows modified in the database.

Comment: No, Its not returning anything. before inserting data it was returning 0. After data insertion it is throwing exception.

Comment: use sqllite expert and open ur db and run the same query , check what is returning .[a reference](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/)

Comment: try this  var existing = db.Query<Person>("select * from Person").FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

First of all use only one object of database through out application.
means if you create a "var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath)" object then use it in whole application.

for insert and delete use :: await database.ExecuteStatementAsync(query);

and for select::

```
 var statement1 = await database.PrepareStatementAsync("");
 while (await statement1.StepAsync())
        {
//statement1.Columns["name"]
         //your logic
        }
```

Try to maintain one common file for query and rendering logic.. It will save time.
All the best..!!